# Mapstruct mapping collections with @Named to object where the signature type of getter and setter differs

Tags: java, mapstruct

Assume the following classes:

```
public class Address {
    public String street;
    ...
}

public class Contact {
    public String boulevard;
    ...
}

public class Partner {
    private final List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<Address>();

    public List<Address> getAddresses() {
        return addresses;
    }
}

public class Person {
    private final ArrayList<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();

    public ArrayList<Contact> getContacts() {
        return contacts;
    }

    //public void setContacts(List<Contact> contacts) {
    public void setContacts(List contacts) {
        /// ...
    }
}
```

This is only a simplified dummy example of a legacy code for illustration.

And here is the mapper:

```
@Mapper
public abstract class PartnerToPersonMapper {
    @BeanMapping(ignoreByDefault = true)
    @Mapping(source="addresses", target = "contacts", qualifiedByName = "mapAddresses")
    public abstract void mapTo(Partner partner, @MappingTarget Person person);

    @Named("mapAddresses")
    List<Contact> mapAddresses(List<Address> addresses) {
        // some complex mapping here
    }
}
```

So if one runs the code as is one gets an implementation for the mapper like:

```
...
        if ( person.getContacts() != null ) {
            List<Address> list = partner.getAddresses();
            if ( list != null ) {
                person.getContacts().clear();
                person.getContacts().addAll( list );
            }
            else {
                person.setContacts( null );
            }
        }
        else {
            List<Address> list = partner.getAddresses();
            if ( list != null ) {
                person.setContacts( new ArrayList( list ) );
            }
        }
...
```

To note is that the `@Named` method was not used by mapstruct at all.
If one uses the commented line `public void setContacts(List<Contact> contacts)` i.e. the signature type of the getter and setter is the same everything works fine (mapstruct uses the `@Named` method):

```
...
if ( person.getContacts() != null ) {
            List<Contact> list = mapAddresses( partner.getAddresses() );
            if ( list != null ) {
...
```

And the question is: assuming I must use the class with different signature types for the getter and setter as I could not change the legacy code.

Is there a way to force mapstruct to apply the `@Named` method anyway (not matter the different getter/setter signature type)?

As only workaround I could use @AfterMapping, but I hope there would be some easier way - or at best the `@Named` with maybe some extra configuration for mapstruct.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `@Named` method needs to be `default`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use expression in @Mapping to strictly use your own method for mapping

Comment: Could you please provide an example (just how the expression would look like with the classes/methods I've used)

Comment: @Mapping(target = "contacts", expression = "java ( mapAddresses( getAddresses() )")

Comment: The correct syntax would be 
`@Mapping(target = "contacts", expression = "java(mapAddresses(partner.getAddresses()))")`
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes sorry, little mistake